# Setter use for dependency injection, passing interface through too many layers

Tags: php, object-oriented, dependency-injection

I have an `Offers` class which is basically a seller which has specific skills, such as law knowledge.
It needs a method `isLawyer`. `Offers` has a `parent_cat_id` column, which references the id of a `Category`.

Here's `Offers` :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Services\CategoryService\AbstractCategory;
use LogicException;

class Offers
{
    /** @var AbstractCategory $category */
    private $categoryService;

    public function isLawyer(): bool
    {
        return $this->getCategoryService()->isLawyer($this->getParentCatId());
    }

    public function setParentCatId(int $catId)
    {
        $this->parent_cat_id = $catId;
    }

    public function getParentCatId(): int
    {
        return (int)$this->parent_cat_id;
    }

    public function setCategoryService(AbstractCategory $categoryService)
    {
        $this->categoryService = $categoryService;
    }

    public function getCategoryService(): AbstractCategory
    {
        if (is_null($this->categoryService)) {
            throw new LogicException('Category service should be set beforehand.');
        }

        return $this->categoryService;
    }
}
```

`AbstractCategory` is an abstract class that different categories will extend. I don't care about the implementation of this as of now.

Now in tests, it's all good and fun :

```
/** @test */
public function is_lawyer_defers_to_category_is_lawyer_method()
{
    $category = Mockery::mock(AbstractCategory::class);
    $category->shouldReceive('isLawyer')->once()->with(1)->andReturn(true);

    $offer = new Offers;
    $offer->setParentCatId(1);
    $offer->setCategoryService($category);

    $this->assertTrue($offer->isLawyer());
}
```

But as for the real implementation, it gets tricky, as I have 3-4 layers before I'm using `$offers->isLawyer()`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Product\Chat;

use App\Models\Offers;

class Chat
{
    /** @var Offers $offer */
    private $offer;

    /**
     * @param Offers $offers
     */
    public function setOffer(Offers $offers)
    {
        $this->offer = $offers;
    }

    /**
     * @return Offers
     */
    public function getOffer()
    {
        return $this->offer;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function byLawyer(): bool
    {
        return $this->getOffer()->isLawyer();
    }
}
```

`Chat` uses `isLawyer` of `Offers`, but `byLawyer` is itself called by something else.

I still need to set the `AbstractCategory` before I use this method.

So, should I pass it through as a parameter to every step ? This sounds ridiculous.

Should I "setup" `Offers` and set the `AbstractCategory` even before it's assigned to the `Chat` ?

Should I give up and instantiate a `new Category` right in the `Offers` class ? Setting the abstraction felt like a better design.

Thanks.

Comment: _I have an `Offers` class which needs a method `isLawyer`_ — I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to accomplish here. What does an "Offers" object represent, and why would it be a lawyer or not? The whole situation makes no sense to me; perhaps some more background information would help.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, I edited the question adding context.

Comment: Are there other categories of offers, or is "lawyer" the only one?

Comment: There are dozens of categories yep.

Answer (score 2):

Your class names are **really** throwing me off.  Perhaps because they are so generically named.  By looking at these classes I have a hard time understanding the interfaces you are trying to expose.

What is a `Chat`?  Why does a chat hold references to `Offers` (which seems to only be a single "offer" so should perhaps be named `Offer`)?  Why would a `Chat` object need a method to check if the `Offers` it holds is `byLawyer` (which perhaps should be named `isLawyer()` since it returns boolean.)?

I just honestly can't make heads or tails of it because I don't think your classes are defined upon real-world lines. Make sure you name your classes meaningfully and specifically, and most importantly with relevance to real-word concepts.  9 times out of 10, if you find yourself thinking of you objects in real-world terms, you will come up with a better design.  In the real world, does a chat have the ability to determine if it has something to do with a lawyer?  No, a chat may need to know about the parties chatting, have some send/receive message functionality, maybe store messaging history, etc.  What does it have to do with lawyers or offers?

What is a CategoryService (ServiceCategory?) and what does it have to do with lawyers (are lawyer services one category of service?)

---

Lots of questions around `Offers`:

- Why would an `Offer(s)` object hold information on categories? Wouldn't this be an opposite relationship in real world terms (where categories hold offers)?
- If you require `AbstractCategory` (or CategoryService) as a dependency for `Offers` why not pass that dependency in constructor?  Why let your class be set up in a bad state?
- Do you really need `Offers` to be mutable, or will it always have a 1-to-1 relationship with CategoryService it wraps?  If so, why the need for the getters/setters?
- Does `Offers` even provide any meaningful functionality above and beyord the `AbstractCategory` object it holds.
- Should `AbstractCategory` truly be an abstract class or an interface?  Usually when you pass a generalized object like this, you are depending on that object having a given interface, not that it inherits from some class. I would seem a bit odd to be type hinting against an abstract class.

---

> ```
> $this->parent_cat_id
> ```

You don't have `parent_cat_id` defined as property on this class.

---

> ```
> return (int)$this->parent_cat_id;
> ```

There should be no reason for type casting here.

---

`Chat` can be set up in a bad state.  `byLawyer()` method can perform unexpectedly if `offer` property has not been set.  Should `Offers` be passed as dependency on constructor?

---

Why inconsistent use of doc blocks?

---

Don't mix camelCase and snake_case in your own code.

---

Why inconsistent use of return type hinting?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I'd love to answer all of this, should I create a new answer or edit yours and add answers to it ?

Comment: @SteveChamaillard  Most of my questions were more hypothetical in nature - hopefully to help prompt some rethinking for how you have structured your classes.  I think you are rightfully concerned about how your objects are interacting and that mainly that concern is based in a current design that does not map well to real-world concepts.